# PHP page not loading generated value on first button click?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single page php application to generate an 8 digit number, user inputs a value and page generates another value, both values are inserted into mysql db and displaying the generated value in an input box at a single button click. Insertion is happening, but generated value is not displaying in the inputbox at the first time, I also tried session its not helping too.

here is my php code,

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['luckyButton']) && $_POST['myLuckyNumber'] != ""){
    //sleep(20);
    $myLuckyNum = $_POST['myLuckyNumber'];
    $resultmyLuckyNum = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lucky where luckyNum='$myLuckyNum'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultmyLuckyNum) > 0) {
        while ($rowmyLuckyNum = mysql_fetch_array($resultmyLuckyNum)) {
            $generatedNumber = $rowmyLuckyNum["generatedNum"];
        }
    }else{
        $gen = getGen();
        $resultGenNum = mysql_query("INSERT INTO lucky (slno, luckyNum, generatedNum) VALUES ( NULL, '$myLuckyNum', '$gen')");
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultGenNum) > 0) {
            $generatedNumber = $gen;
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text"class="inputs" name="myLuckyNumber" onClick="this.select();" placeholder="Enter You Lucky Number" value="<?php echo $myLuckyNum; ?>" />
<input type="submit" class="css_button" name="luckyButton" value="Check"/>
</form>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<?php
if($generatedNumber != ""){
    echo '<input type="text" name="myLuckyNumber" onClick="this.select();" id="generatedNumber" readonly="true" value="' . $generatedNumber . '" />';
}
echo '<p id="errText"> ' . $err . ' </p>';
function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }
    return $key;
}
function getGen(){
    $gen1 = random_string(8);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lucky where generatedNum='$gen1'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($row["generatedNum"] == $gen1){
                getGen();
            }
        }
    }else{
        //echo $gen1;
        return($gen1);
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

my table,.

```
CREATE TABLE `lucky` (
`slno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `luckyNum` text NOT NULL,
  `generatedNum` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: use if(isset($generatedNumber) && $generatedNumber != ""){ echo '<input type="text" name="myLuckyNumber" onClick="this.select();" id="generatedNumber" readonly="true" value="' . $generatedNumber . '" />';}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `mysql_num_rows` will return either `0` or `1`, use it like

```
if($resultGenNum === 1){
       $generatedNumber = $gen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_num_rows` in a wrong way. When you run insert query, it does not return rows, it returns true or false (Boolean). When it will return true, you will get `1` (as `$resultGenNum`).
**use this instead:**

```
 if ($resultGenNum === 1){
       $generatedNumber = $gen;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if ( $generatedNumber != "" )`, perhaps you should try something like `if ( isset( $generatedNumber ) )`.

If `$generatedNumber` doesn't exist (which it doesn't if nothing was posted to the script), then the comparison will fail (in fact, you're probably getting a PHP error).

Of course, that leads us to the next problem - if nothing is posted to the script, you don't generate a number. So of course, if you don't generate a number, there is no number to display. So you should structure your code in such a way that a random number is always generated - regardless of whether a post variable was received or not.